# Is there a function or option to collect factors under one radical sign?

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic

One of the things that frustrates me most about *Mathematica*'s symbolic manipulations is the fact that output is often presented quite differently than most humans would write it. This is especially egregious when square roots are involved. For example, *Mathematica* will output this

[image: standard format for radicals]

when I think most humans (or at least physicists) would consider this to be "simpler":

[image: desirable format for radicals]

or, alternatively,

[image: other desirable format]

My question is: Is there any simplification function, option, or other trick for coercing *Mathematica* into formatting an output thusly? I have so far not had any success finding one, and I've explored various simplification formulas as well as trying to apply assumptions about the variables (real, positive, etc.) -- though maybe I just haven't stumbled on the right one.

Comment: Providing copyable code will increase the likelihood and speed of answers.

Comment: I get nervous whenever factions start to collect under one radical.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transformation is not *generally* true; if you provide [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) with your assumptions you get a better result:

```
expr = (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Ea - g L m])/Sqrt[m];

FullSimplify[expr, m > 0]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[-2 g L + (2 Ea)/m]
> ```

Comment: Nice… Though I'd still like to factor out the 2, but leave it under the radical? More broadly, is there a general strategy for making Mathematica expressions more like what we normally write?

Comment: @ibeatty You could `Factor` the expression under the radical but then *Mathematica* would automatically convert it to `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-((-Ea + g L m)/m)]`.  I am not aware of any general and successful strategy to make *Mathematica* format expressions in "human" form, though there are tools and formats that are at least useful, e.g. `TraditionalForm`, `HornerForm`, etc.  This has been asked before; I'll try to find a reference.

Comment: Why is *Mathematica* not returning `FullSimplify[Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[5], a > 0]` as `Sqrt[a/5]`?